# How to reuse a function inside a where in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-3.0

I have a query that select all Photos if its public, and only if friends if visibility is private in this code.

```
_communityDbContext
            .Photos
            .Where(x => (
                    x.Privacy == 1 ||
                    (x.Privacy == 2 &&
                     _communityDbContext.Friendships.FirstOrDefault(d => x.CreatedBy.Id == user1 && d.FriendUser.Id == user2) !=
                     null)
                )
            );
```

But I trying to extract this piece of code to reuse in another queries

```
_communityDbContext.Friendships.FirstOrDefault(d => x.CreatedBy.Id == user1 && d.FriendUser.Id == user2) != null
```

Is possible to call an function and make the code like that:

```
_communityDbContext
            .Photos
            .Where(x => (
                    x.Privacy == 1 ||
                    (x.Privacy == 2 &&
                    hasFriendship(x.CreatedBy.Id, user))
                )
            );
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question but may be worth doing.... you can replace `_communityDbContext.Friendships.FirstOrDefault(d => x.CreatedBy.Id == 3 && d.FriendUser.Id == 3) != null` with `_communityDbContext.Friendships.Any(d => x.CreatedBy.Id == 3 && d.FriendUser.Id == 3)` ... this would return `true` if there were any matches and false otherwise, it removes the need to check for null.

Comment: Check out Predicate Builder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).  It may help you out

Comment: `x.CreatedBy.Id == 3` doesn't seem to belong there in that reusable function, it's not related in any sense to `Friendship`. I'm also trying to figure out how is that `user` variable you're passing into a reusable function used, but didn't figure it out so far...

Answer (score 1):

I fond a solution, the method invocation must be done to an expression, not to a function call. So I can extract that part of code by doing

```
public Expression<Func<Photo, bool>> Visible()
    {
        return x => (
            x.Privacy == 1 ||
            (x.Privacy == 2 &&
             _communityDbContext.Friendships.FirstOrDefault(d => x.CreatedBy.Id == 3 && d.FriendUser.Id == 3) !=
             null)
        );
    }
```

And calling this by

```
.where(Visible())
```